# stopping the right click and go to link function for a tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tag like below. The question I have is how do I make this `<a/>` tag not behave like a link when user right clicks it. Since on a regular click the `onclick` event will fire and return false I am good with the regular click on the link the issue comes when a user right clicks the mouse and then gets the option like open in new tab or open in new window I have to prevent this from happening. I found out I can use `javascript:void(0)` in the href to do that but for some reason I cannot change the href as it is used for some other stuff. Is there any even or something that I can use.

```
<A title="Test1" onclick="javascript:search1('search'); return false;"href="team">search</A>
```

Thanks

Comment: "*...I have to prevent the right click and go to link functionality...*," can you rephrase it?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, other than changing the URL so it's nothing useful anyway (To # for example). I believe the go to url function in the right click dialogue is the browser grabbing the href attribute and redirects you to it. I'm glad such a thing can't be interrupted, people could make spam sites much more annoying

Comment: change the href to `javascript:void(0);` and for the other stuff use the HTML5 `data` attribute. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml

Comment: Don't use HTML5 but is there any other attribute that I can use .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as often, there's no universal solution, every browser do it its way. HTML 5 says form.oncontextmenu event handler should be supported. So this

```
<script>
    document.oncontextmenu=function("alert('dont play with sources');return false");
</script>
```

should work if you use HTML 5.

you can also remove the javascript word, onclick already waits for js code (as oncontextmenu does).

```
  <a onclick="search1('....
```

Comment: You should look at the compatible browsers for oncontextmenu event :
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html